# This project cannot be viewed in the object browser. Ошибка c#

Tags: c#, ssh, sftp

У меня есть программа на c#. Я хочу установить себе вот эту штуку : [ссылка](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/)

Делаю всё по инструкции : [ссылка](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20enhance%20debugging%20experience%20with%20SSH.NET&referringTitle=Documentation)

Библиотеки подключаются

```
using Renci.SshNet;
using Renci.SshNet.Common;
using Renci.SshNet.Sftp;
```

Но во время комплектовки они подчерчериваются синей, волнистой линией и выдается такая ошибка:

> Error  1   The type or namespace name 'Renci' could not be found (are you >missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    Z:\RF\Программы для >Терминалов\TRF(FTP download)\TRF\MainForm.cs   5   7   TRF

И еще в `SolutionExplorer > Renci.SshNet > Reference` есть элемент  `Microsoft.CSharp`, у него желтый треугольник, и при попытке открыть его выдается такое:

> This project cannot be viewed in the object browser because it is unavailable > or not yet build. Please ensure that the project us available and build.

Что мне делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта инструкция объясняет как собрать отладочную копию библиотеки - чтобы что-то в ней править или дописывать. Вы же, судя по всему, дописывать ее не собираетесь, просто хотите использовать из своего кода. Удалите проект с исходниками из Solution Explorer. И поставьте бинарники:

Пакет SSH.NET есть [в NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SSH.NET/2014.4.6-beta2).

Menu -> View -> Other Windows -> Package Manager Console.

Выберите проект, к которому вы хотите подключить SSH.NET в дропдауне, и выполните:

```
Install-Package SSH.NET -Pre
```

Если очень хочется поставить вручную:

Скачайте со [страницы последнего релиза](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/120565) zip, на котором написано binaries (для 3.5 или для 4, смотря какая у вас версия). Распакуйте его, и подключите к своему проекту (через Solution Explorer / Add Reference / Browse).

Comment: Спасибо большое) Очень помог)